# Why isn't my hover box mobile responsive?

Tags: css

I need some help with hover diplay area which does fully cover the text on mobile but it does on desktop version. Any idea what I can do to solve this?
It's hover element under founder's picture.
https://www.webleviathan.com/#team

Thanks so much in advance peeople.
Tony

Answer (score 0):

```
.team-member:hover .details {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

is the cause, add this selector to your media break for mobile.

use a em or a vh instead of a px.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't really do the job :( I made the text a lot smaller using em but if I enlarge the size it still gets cut off again.

Comment: Tony, sorry about that, I just got online and seen the answer I posted was vague.

Answer (score 0):

Tony, 
So your class for that div is `.details`
Your current css for that class is

```
.team-member:hover .details, .team-member:focus .details {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
    background: #333;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.team-member .details {
    position: absolute;
    top: -200px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 190px;
    padding: 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

and I see this.
[image: desktop view]
Your CMS is using bootstrap and as such when I change my viewport to a more mobile size... I get this
[image]

This is because bootstrap is not a [Device Responsive Design framework](https://www.jeremiahstillings.net/device-responsive-design/) but rather a very old mobile first concept.

Digging a little on your CMS and theme I see WordPress 4.9.8 running theme Zerif-Lite

I am a huge fan of WP and Zerif-lite **was** an awesome theme 
Times change... the theme your using is really not for wp 4.9.8 for reasons your seeing.
They have a new theme out that replaces that one that does not work well with the newer WP.
https://themeisle.com/themes/zelle-lite/

As WP changes devs must keep up with the changes and sometimes the old and working becomes the defunct and problem-some not due to the theme devs work but the platform changes.

Bootstrap was what it was based on. Bootstrap was a project by twitter in 
 * Bootstrap v3.1.1 (http://getbootstrap.com)

- Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
- Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)

Bootstrap is now under another team and "wrapping" bootstrap as your UI in a theme is considered yesterdays tech.

Can you make that Zerif-lite theme do what you seek with bootstrap? ABSOLUTELY! You will need a full education of CSS3 though or a very adept web dev.

If you are a programmer type you can find the answer in using [media querys](http://cssmediaqueries.com/) to tweak that theme but I do not recommend this approach, I recommend upgrading your theme.